# (for five lunches) vs (five days of lunch) vs (lunch for five days) vs (for five meals)

Tags: sentence-construction

I have made up the sentences below.

(1) There is enough food for us for five lunches.

(2) There is enough food for us for five days of lunch.

(3) There is enough food for us for lunch for five days.

(4) There is enough food for us for five meals.

I am not sure which way makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

1 is fine.

2 sounds a bit odd, almost like you'll be eating lunch for the entire day, though it is understandable and would sound acceptable. You could also lengthen it to "five days' worth of lunch", which I prefer, but the prior "lunch for the entire day" point could still be argued for this phrasing too.

3 sounds okay, but I think 1 is much more idiomatic and preferable.

4 is also fine, but bear in mind that a "meal" could mean any meal, and not necessarily a lunch.